# C: Help understanding pointers

Tags: c, pointers, hashmap

I have been building this hash table function that is given an array it gets a word from and a pointer to an array that it fills with my linked list struct. It compiles correctly but I get a segmentation fault at - *hashTable[hashVal] = *newNode; .

```
void hashTableCreate(char *array, list *hashTable[]) {

while(arrayPos < getArrayLength(array)) {

    char *temp = getWord(array);
    int hashVal = hashingFunc(temp);
    if((*hashTable[hashVal]).word == temp ) {
        (*hashTable[hashVal]).count = (*hashTable[hashVal]).count+1;
    }
    else {
        list *newNode = malloc(sizeof(list));
        strcpy(newNode->word,temp);
        newNode->count = 1;
        *hashTable[hashVal] = *newNode;
    }
}
}
```

It's called like this:

```
void timeStructures(char *newArray) {
    list *hashTable[3000];
    hashTableCreate(newArray, hashTable);
}
```

I know this is to do with the way I am using my pointers but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want `hashTable[hashVal] = newNode`. What you have, `*hashTable[hashVal]`, is wrong because it dereferences `hashTable[hashVal]` but none of your array entries are initialized. In fact, you need to init your `hashTable` so that all its entries are NULL so that you can check for that and not dereference any NULL entries. At the moment your code is accessing invalid memory all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems on this code:

1. You seem you are using extra asterisks when assigning `newNode` to `hashTable`.
2. You can use `++` operator to increment `count`, and use `->` to access a member of a pointer to struct.
3. `getWord` is unknown to me, but seems impossible it can return a pointer to a string contained inside an element of `hashTable`, which means the next `if` will always be false (`newNode`'s `word` is a copied string, not a pointer to `array`'s word), as it compares memory addresses instead of strings.
4. You never free `temp` neither `hashTable` elements, which seems another misconception of what you are doing here.
5. As noted by @kaylum , you should initialize `hashTable` so you avoid comparing against unassigned array elements, neither modifying `count` on them.
6. `hashTable` has to be passed as a pointer to `hashTableCreate`, or this will work on a copied version of it:

Try this:

```
void hashTableCreate(char *array, list *(*hashTable[])) {

   while(arrayPos < getArrayLength(array)) {

      char *temp = getWord(array);
      int hashVal = hashingFunc(temp);

      if((*hashTable)[hashVal] != NULL &&
         strcmp((*hashTable)[hashVal]->word, temp) == 0 ) {
         (*hashTable)[hashVal]->count++;
      }
      else {
         list *newNode = malloc(sizeof(list));
         strcpy(newNode->word,temp);
         newNode->count = 1;
         (*hashTable)[hashVal] = newNode;
      }

      free(temp);
   }
}

void timeStructures(char *newArray) {
   list *hashTable[3000];
   int i;

   // Initialize hashTable pointers to NULL
   for(i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      hashTable[i] = NULL;
   }

   hashTableCreate(newArray, &hashTable);

   // Free hashTable elements, malloc'ed at hashTableCreate
   for(i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
      if(hashTable[i] != NULL) {
         free(hashTable[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Note 1: you never check if `hashVal` is higher than 3000, which might be fine if you know what you are doing, aka, you know `hashingFunc` will never return 3000 or higher. If you do not, you'll need to care about growing `hashTable` appropriately.

Note 2: executing `getArrayLength` on each loop might be a performance problem for large lists. You probably prefer to create a variable to contain its value and execute it only once.

Note 3: It might be some easier if you declare `hashTable` as a plain list of elements, not a list of pointers to elements, like `list hashTable[3000];`, but I don't know exactly what you're looking for. Also, it will always waste 3000 `list` elements of memory, so might be a performance problem.